# Dynamically create a PDF with a background image

Tags: php, pdf

I'm trying to dynamically create a PDF (on the server) with some text on top of a pre-defined background image. I'm using PHP and I can't seem to find anyway to do this.

I've looked into http://www.fpdf.org/ and a bunch of other options.

I'm not opposed to using Flash either if it will do the trick.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Show us how you tried to use the Image() function and what didnt work.

Comment: Doesn't fpdf's `Image()` do the trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should take a look at [this](http://www.mpdf1.com/) class, I really love it. 
It renders HTML to PDF, and if you define a Background-Image with CSS it will be in the created PDF.

Comment: As ipalaus said, excellent find, added to my resources folder!

Comment: Very easy to use, now I'm off to adding passwords.
Thanks!

Comment: For anyone still interested in this, the provided URL no longer functions.

Comment: please share the link again. there is error with the page when i click on it.

Answer (score 25):

With [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) you can do it like this:

```
$fpdf = new FPDF();
$fpdf->AddPage();
$fpdf->Image('background-image.png', 0, 0, $fpdf->w, $fpdf->h);
$fpdf->Output();
```

Old question I know, but this might help someone.

Comment: How do i get a PDF as background image?

Answer (score 2):

Another good alternative is [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/), it also supports (basic) HTML as output. Just look at the [TCPDF Examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) for a quick overview of what it can do (Example 51 might be helpful for you).

Comment: can we use `background-image` in TCPDF ??

Comment: TCPDF supports everything FPDF does and more (e.g. SVG)

Answer (score 0):

Also, [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf).

You were thinking too hard about what you wanted to do ;) ... always start with something you're familiar with (PHP, HTML) and see if there's something that will create the desired result (PDF). For a full list of converters you could try see the community wiki [List of HTML to PDF converters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3178448/264628) (it covers more than just PHP-based libraries).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to re-order your code. 
Then your next content will automatically placed on the top of the image.
example:

```
$fpdf = new FPDF();
$fpdf->AddPage();

// put the image in first order
$fpdf->Image('background-image.png', 0, 0, $fpdf->w, $fpdf->h);

$fpdf->cell(...);
...
...
$fpdf->Output();
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that!

Comment: @makata it's worked. maybe you need to set the X and Y also.

Comment: This throws an error “Cannot access protected property FPDF::$w”