# How to set backgroundimage using fpdf?

Tags: php, image, pdf, background, fpdf

I am using fpdf and PHP to create pdf in my website , and i  want to set an image as background for the table in that pdf. How can i set this background image using fpdf?  Can anyone give an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically create a PDF with a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006153/dynamically-create-a-pdf-with-a-background-image)

Comment: I have checked this page , there was an answer with a reference url but this reference link http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php is not working now.

Comment: Look further down at the 2nd answer. It shows you very clearly how to do it.